# How to block ubuntu internet access?

Tags: ubuntu, ufw

I would like to block internet access in the browser (firefox) but when trying to do it with ufw it simply does nothing, try

```
sudo ufw deny 80
sudo ufw deny 8080
sudo ufw deny 443
```

but nothing, will they have any idea?

Comment: Instead of "deny", use "deny out" . Note that this will also block system software updates. If you just want to block browser access for particular users, please edit the question to clarify.